# How to compute linear acceleration in 3D from change in roll, pitch and yaw angles?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration, coordinate-systems, rotational-kinematics, rotation

We know that if a body is rotating only about $z$-axis along a circle of radius $R$ with an angular rate of $\omega$, then the acceleration of the body in 3D is $a = [0.0\ \ \omega^2R \ \ 0.0]$. Now let us assume that the body is rotating in 3D such that the change in its roll, pitch and yaw angles in time interval dt is $\left[d\phi\ \ d\theta \ \ d\psi \right]$, respectively. The corresponding radii are $R_1, R_2 , R_3$. Let us also define the following:
$\omega_x =  \frac{d\phi}{dt}, \omega_y =  \frac{d\theta}{dt}, \omega_z =  \frac{d\psi}{dt}$.

There is no other motion in any direction. How do we compute the instantaneous acceleration in 3D? Is it simply $a = [\omega_y^2R_2 \ \ \omega_z^2R_3 \ \ \omega_x^2R_2]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def \b {\mathbf}$

Start with the Position vector $~\b P$
\begin{align*}
   &\b P=\b S\,\b R\tag 1
 \end{align*}
where $~\b S=\b S_z(\psi)\,\b S_y(\theta)\,\,\b S_x(\phi)~$ is the rotation matrix and $~\psi,\theta,\phi~$ are the
yaw, pitch , roll angles

the acceleration

\begin{align*}
   &\b{\ddot{P}}=\b{\ddot{ S}}\,\b R\quad\text{with}\quad
   \b{\dot{S}}=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-\omega_{{z}}&\omega_{{y}}
\\ \omega_{{z}}&0&-\omega_{{x}}\\
-\omega_{{y}}&\omega_{{x}}&0\end {array} \right]
\b S
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 &\b{\ddot{P}}=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-\omega_{{z}}&\omega_{{y}}
\\ \omega_{{z}}&0&-\omega_{{x}}\\
-\omega_{{y}}&\omega_{{x}}&0\end {array} \right]
\,\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-\omega_{{z}}&\omega_{{y}}
\\ \omega_{{z}}&0&-\omega_{{x}}\\
-\omega_{{y}}&\omega_{{x}}&0\end {array} \right]
\b S(\psi,\theta,\phi)\,\b R\tag 2
 \end{align*}
to solve  equation (2) you need additional equation which is:
\begin{align*}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     \dot{\psi} \\
     \dot{\theta} \\
     \dot{\phi} \\
   \end{bmatrix}= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} {\frac {\cos \left( \psi \right) \sin
 \left( \theta \right) }{\cos \left( \theta \right) }}&{\frac {\sin
 \left( \psi \right) \sin \left( \theta \right) }{\cos \left( \theta
 \right) }}&1\\ -\sin \left( \psi \right) &\cos
 \left( \psi \right) &0\\ {\frac {\cos \left( \psi
 \right) }{\cos \left( \theta \right) }}&{\frac {\sin \left( \psi
 \right) }{\cos \left( \theta \right) }}&0\end {array} \right]
\,\begin{bmatrix}
    \omega_x \\
     \omega_y \\
     \omega_z \\
   \end{bmatrix}
 \end{align*}

---

for small angles

\begin{align*}
 \b S&\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}
               1 & 0 & 0 \\
               0 & 1 & 0 \\
               0 & 0 & 1 \\
             \end{bmatrix}
             +\begin{bmatrix}
               0 & -\psi & \theta \\
               \psi & 0 & -\phi \\
               -\theta &  \phi &0 \\
             \end{bmatrix}\quad,
  \begin{bmatrix}
     \dot{\phi} \\
     \dot{\theta} \\
     \dot{\psi} \\
   \end{bmatrix}\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}
    \omega_x \\
     \omega_y \\
     \omega_z \\
   \end{bmatrix}    \quad\Rightarrow\\
   &  \begin{bmatrix}
     {\phi} \\
     {\theta} \\
     {\psi} \\
   \end{bmatrix}  =  \begin{bmatrix}
    \omega_x \\
     \omega_y \\
     \omega_z \\
   \end{bmatrix}   \,t+\begin{bmatrix}
     {\phi_0} \\
     {\theta_0} \\
     {\psi_0} \\
   \end{bmatrix} 
 \end{align*}
thus you obtain analytical solution for equation (2)

Comment: Is $\mathbf{R} = \left[R_1 \ \ R_2 \  \ R_3\right]^T$?

Comment: Yes  this is correct